# SwiftUI on iPadOS - Navigation randomly stops working when in split view

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is on iPadOS 15.5. I am on Xcode 13.4.1, which is the latest release.

I have the following app:

```swift
@main
struct ipadViewTestsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("About")
                    } label: {
                        Label("About", systemImage: "info.circle")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Settings")
                    } label: {
                        Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Sidebar Test")
                
                Text("Please make a selection. ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the application is in split mode and in the narrowest configuration. The navigation would just randomly stop working.

Please see the below GIF for a demonstration.

[image: GIF demonstration]

As shown in the GIF, when clicking on Above and Settings, the view would not transition. I have done some searches and many tutorials about SwiftUI on iPadOS that use sidebars seems to follow the same pattern as my code's. I can't find anything on Apple's official website except `NavigationSplitView` for the upcoming iPadOS 16.

Comment: From the GIF it seems that it stops working, when the area is too narrow. Perhaps, iPadOS expects you to switch to the stack-based navigation, when there's not enough space for a split mode. Just a guess, however.

Comment: When the view freezes, it's always good to see if there's anything blocking the main thread. Could you check the CPU report as you run the same actions?

Comment: @LucasChae Nothing in the main thread as far as I can see. Also the view didn't freeze per se, if I may add. When I clicked on `NavigationLink`, the view still responses to any touch, it just doesn't transition

Comment: @lazarevzubov Thanks for the suggestion. I have to admit that this behaviour is a bit random, I can't really pinpoint what causes this.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's random. It happens when a selection is made in regular width and then changing to compact. The navigation link is still working, i.e. the detail is being replaced, it is just not pushing the view controller. It's one of the many bugs in NavigationView and why they have redesigned it into 2 components now, but it has just as many if not more issues.

Comment: @malhal Thank you. To be honest, I would not be surprised if this is a bug. Looks like I will have to use `NavigationSplitView` when iOS 16 comes out.